# How to make a rigid PayPal REST API Payment cycle?

Tags: paypal, flask, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm fiddling with paypalrestsdk on my Flask app and here is the sequence for the payment. Could anyone experienced point out whether the cycle is rigid or not?

1. Create payment with appropriate redirect URLs.

   ```
   payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
       "intent": "sale",
       "payer": {
           "payment_method": "paypal"
       },
       "redirect_urls": {
           "return_url": url_for('.payment_success', _external=True),
           "cancel_url": url_for('.payment_cancel', _external=True)
       },
   ...})
   if payment.create():
         ...
   ```
2. If successful, save the following payment response details in the database.

   ```
   class PayPalPayment(db.Model):
       __tablename__ = 'ediket_paypal_payment'
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ediket_ediketuser.id'))
       payment_id = db.Column(db.String(30))
       amount = db.Column(db.String(10))
       state = db.Column(db.String(10))
       redirect_url = db.Column(db.VARCHAR)
       created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
       updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
   ```
3. Then, redirect using HATEOAS links.
4. Transaction proceeds in PayPal. Redirects to return url.
5. Find Current User's last transaction with 'created' status from database.

   ```
   pending_payment = PayPalPayment.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).filter_by(state='created').first()
   ```
6. Execute Payment using payment_id and payer_id

   ```
   payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(pending_payment.payment_id)
   if payment.execute({"payer_id": request.args.get('PayerID')}):
       #We are done!
       #Update Payment model for completion
   ```

It all works fine, but I'm not too convinced whether this flow is safe for real world application. Since the return url only contains PayerID and Token, the only way to locate the relevant payment to execute is through blind query on Payment table using current user id and status='created'.

Is there a room for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any modification since then was that I stored extra field called token, which is passed with HATEOAS links. By storing this token, I was able to locate user's pending payment to proceed with execute.

**Update:**

Here is the implementation detail. It may not be perfect but it did the trick for now.

```
class PayPalPayment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'paypal_payment'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    payment_id = db.Column(db.String(30))
    amount = db.Column(db.String(10))
    state = db.Column(db.String(10))
    token = db.Column(db.String(30))
    redirect_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, payment, product_id, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.payment_id = payment.id
        self.amount = payment.transactions[0].amount.total
        self.state = payment.state

        self.created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(payment.create_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        self.updated_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(payment.update_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

        for link in payment.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                self.redirect_url = link.href

        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(self.redirect_url)
        self.token = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['token'][0]

@payment_view.route('/paypal', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def paypal_payment():
    user_id = current_user.get_id()
    product = Product.query.filter_by(id=request.form.get('product')).first_or_404()
    past = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
    count = PayPalPayment.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).filter_by(state='created').filter(PayPalPayment.created_at >= past).count()

    # To prevent a spam where user creates Payment and never comes back to it
    if count > 4:
        return Response(render_template('payment/overflow.html'), mimetype='text/html')

    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": url_for('.payment_success', _external=True),
            "cancel_url": url_for('.payment_cancel', _external=True)
        },

        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "total": product.amount,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "description": product.description
        }]
    })

    if payment.create():
        new_payment = PayPalPayment(payment, product.id, user_id)
        db.session.add(new_payment)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(new_payment.redirect_url, code=302)
    else:
        return Response(render_template('payment/cancel.html'), mimetype='text/html')

@payment_view.route('/success')
@login_required
def payment_success():
    user_id = current_user.get_id()
    payerID = request.args.get('PayerID', None)
    token = request.args.get('token', None)

    pending_payment = PayPalPayment.query.filter_by(token=token).filter_by(state='created').first_or_404()

    try:
        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(pending_payment.payment_id)
    except paypalrestsdk.exceptions.ResourceNotFound:
        abort(404)

    template = 'payment/error.html'
    if payment.execute({"payer_id": request.args.get('PayerID')}):
        pending_payment.state = payment.state
        pending_payment.updated_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(payment.update_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        template = 'payment/success.html'

    db.session.commit()
    return Response(render_template(template), mimetype='text/html')
```

Please feel free to criticize.

Comment: if this answers problem, then accept your own answer so it can be marked as closed; I would +1 it if you provided code so answer is easier to understand